# How to make old RemoteInput still valid when during voice input further notification updates come?

Tags: android, notifications

I'm developing an android app with android wear support.

In this app, I have a Service running on start and keep sending notification updates(with the same notification id) every 5 seconds to inform user of updated info and expects user reaction by adding action with RemoteInput so that user reacts with voice input.

The problem is, since the notification updates every 5 seconds, it is possible that during the voice input on the wear side, another notification has been fired and makes the current PendingIntent invalid, thus the user voice input will be not taken to the running Service to get processed.

If I put the updates interval to 20 seconds or even longer and do the voice input immediately after the updates on the wear side, then I can get the voice input on the Service side.

Because I'm developing a real time app that needs to inform user of updated info in real time, the notification updates interval should be not longer than 5 seconds...

I've also tried to set PendingIntent with different flag options but that didn't help.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks!